Issues with PHPStan Validation for Array Conversion to Integers
I'm new to using PHPStan/Larastan and configured it based on their documentation. When I run PHPStan at level 8, it passes without errors However, when I set PHPStan to the maximum level, it generates the following error:
I have an array of input data that I retrieve with the following code:
$num = $request->input('num', []);
I want to convert each element of $num from a string to an integer, so I use a foreach loop like this:
foreach ($num as $key => $value) { $num[$key] = (int) $value; }
When I run PHPStan, it fails with the following message:
Line Controllers\CalculationController.php
------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:25    Argument of an invalid type mixed supplied for foreach, only iterables are supported.
:26    Cannot access offset mixed on mixed.
:26    Cannot cast mixed to int.
:29    Only iterables can be unpacked, mixed given in argument #1.

How can I resolve these issues and ensure PHPStan does not report these errors?
my goal is to convert array of string to int i try 3 possible way

forloop

$num = $request->input('num', []);

foreach ($num as $key => $value) {
    $num[$key] = (int) $value;
}

error:
 ------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Line   Controllers\CalculationController.php
 ------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :25    Argument of an invalid type mixed supplied for foreach, only iterables are supported.
  :26    Cannot access offset mixed on mixed.
  :26    Cannot cast mixed to int.
  :29    Only iterables can be unpacked, mixed given in argument #1.
 ------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


forloop with pointer

 $num = $request->input('num', []);

 foreach ($num as &$value) {
    $value = (int) $value;
 }

error:
 ------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Line   Controllers\CalculationController.php
 ------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :25    Argument of an invalid type mixed supplied for foreach, only iterables are supported.
  :26    Cannot cast mixed to int.
  :29    Only iterables can be unpacked, mixed given in argument #1.
 ------ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


array_map

 $num = array_map('intval', $request->input('num', []));

error:
 ------ ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
  Line   Controllers\CalculationController.php
 ------ ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
  :23    Parameter #1 $callback of function array_map expects (callable(mixed): mixed)|null, 'intval' given.      
          Type array|bool|float|int|resource|string|null of parameter #1 $value of passed callable needs to     
            be same or wider than parameter type mixed of accepting callable.
  :23    Parameter #2 $array of function array_map expects array, mixed given.
 ------ ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    


array_map with closer

$num = array_map(function (string $value): int {
            return intval($value);
        }, $request->input('num', []));

error:
 ------ ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
  Line   Controllers\CalculationController.php
 ------ ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
  :23    Parameter #1 $callback of function array_map expects (callable(mixed): mixed)|null, Closure(string):  
         int given.
          Type string of parameter #1 $value of passed callable needs to be same or wider than parameter     
            type mixed of accepting callable.
  :25    Parameter #2 $array of function array_map expects array, mixed given.
 ------ ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 



how would changing the way you loop fix anything? The error seems very clear "Argument of an invalid type mixed supplied for foreach". Tell PHPStan that your value is an array or don't use the maximum level of reporting.

What is the standard level of reporting? I thought a more detailed (maximal) level would be better.

Request::input returns mixed. It has no way of knowing whats inside your request body, you're going to have to define the type yourself.
/**
 * @var array<string, string> $num
 */
$num = $request->input('num', []);

foreach ($num as $key => $value) {
    $num[$key] = (int) $value;
}


its work thanks.
